# Ssocket exception in AWS AppSync in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, aws-amplify, flutter-dependencies, aws-appsync

I am working on flutter application with AWS AppSync in that I am using the end URL of AWS server but when I try to execute the query I am getting below error

I am working in proxy setting but is not effecting this URL it's working perfectly in native android application

**SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = XXXXXXXXXXXXX.appsync-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com port -43872**

I have a search on google but they mention the internet permission in not added in the manifest file but after added the permission I am facing the same issue.

Below is the code on the AWS app sync execute method where I am getting the error.

```
Future<Map> execute({
  @required String endpoint,
  @required String query,
  @required Map variables,
  @required String accessToken,
  Database cache,
  CachePriority priority = CachePriority.network,
}) async {
  var body = jsonEncode({"query": query, "variables": variables});

  Future<Map> loadFromCache() async {
    var cacheKey = getCacheKey(endpoint, body);
    var data = await readCache(cache, cacheKey);
    if (data != null) {
      logger.fine(
        'loaded from cache (endpoint: ${endpoint.toRepr()}, requestBody: ${body.toRepr()}, cacheKey: $cacheKey)',
      );
    }
    return data;
  }

  if (cache != null && priority == CachePriority.cache) {
    var data = await loadFromCache();
    if (data != null) return data;
  }

  logger.fine('POST ${endpoint.toRepr()} - ${body.toRepr()}');

  http.Response response;
  try {
    response = await http.post(
      endpoint,
      headers: {
        HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: AWSaccessToken,
        HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: ContentType.json.mimeType,
        "x-api-key" :AWS_APP_SYNC_KEY,
      },
      body: body,
    );
  } catch (e) {
    var shouldFallback = cache != null && priority == CachePriority.network;
    if (!shouldFallback || !isNetworkError(e)) rethrow;

    logger.finest('network error encountered; falling back to cache - $e');

    var data = await loadFromCache();
    if (data != null) {
      return data;
    } else {
      rethrow;
    }
  }

  if (response.statusCode != HttpStatus.ok) {
    throw HttpError(response);
  }

  logger.fine(
    'loaded from network (endpoint: ${endpoint.toRepr()}, requestBody: ${body.toRepr()})',
  );
  var result = jsonDecode(response.body);
  var data = result["data"];

  if (cache != null) {
    var cacheKey = getCacheKey(endpoint, body);
    await updateCache(cache, cacheKey, data);
    logger.fine(
      'updated cache (endpoint: ${endpoint.toRepr()}, requestBody: ${body.toRepr()}, cacheKey: $cacheKey)',
    );
  }

  return data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are connecting to the wrong port, I mean the port you are connecting to from your client has no listener/server, or the port and public IP is not exposed to the internet on your server side